# Amazon S3 Permission Issue

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3

I have 2 buckets for my application:
- gambify-dev-devil ( for development)
- gambify-prod (for production)

I have set them up absolutely identical, but for my production I have issues accessing some ressources. My production environment is a pagodabox. I use Gaufrette, LiipImagine and Vichuploader for my File handling. The issue I have is that in my production environment seems that either my application requests the wrong ressources or that there is an access issue. Because I have a lot logs indicating the an AccessDenied error within my bucket:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>D90C05F182C91003</RequestId>
<HostId>
i7SkwNCbyUnCCBCnkyyrv7x9pOLGtr4sUgqWYkJMqk0X0lXYIW5zeu4688FCqBiA
</HostId>
</Error>
```

In order to investigate this issue further (I really have no idea where it is coming from because its working fine in every other environment and also in production it was working fine 2 weeks ago), I would like to see which ressource was requested. Is there a chance to find the URL that was requested or who tried to request what, that caused this issue? Because if I provide a correct path to an existing ressouce the bucket works fine:
e.g: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gambify-prod/profile/default.png

Update:
Now I found the real error message that is causing me problems:

> 04fadbab7a82c23143855d5c918e1ba8fa32ef1d622c00a3daa9fcdc6daf5d90
>   gambify-prod [05/Aug/2013:19:03:57 +0000] 173.193.185.250 -
>   133EF43443891C63 REST.HEAD.OBJECT
>   profile_thumb_small/51e9a03453c80.jpeg "HEAD
>   /profile_thumb_small/51e9a03453c80.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 403
>   SignatureDoesNotMatch 1015 - 7 -
>   "https://gambify-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/profile_thumb_small/51e9a03453c80.jpeg"
>   "aws-sdk-php/1.5.17.1 PHP/5.3.23 Linux/2.6.32-042stab068.8 Arch/x86_64
>   SAPI/fpm-fcgi Integer/9223372036854775807 Build/20121126140000
>   simplexml/0.1 json/1.2.1 pcre/8.31 spl/0.2 curl/7.19.7 openssl/0.9.8k
>   apc/3.1.9 pdo/1.0.4dev pdo_sqlite/1.0.1 sqlite/2.0-dev sqlite3/0.7-dev
>   zlib/1.1 memory_limit/200M date.timezone/Europe.Berlin
>   open_basedir/off safe_mode/off zend.enable_gc/on" -

I still have no idea what is causing the initial issue.

Moved the discussion about the signature error to: [Amazon S3 signature not working with SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071842/amazon-s3-signature-not-working-with-sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, you can configure your production bucket to keep a log of all the requests made against it, similar to an Apache or other web server access log.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html

Once you have logging enabled, you will be able to find out the URL of the request, who requested it and when it was requested.

**Update:**

If an AccessDenied error is returned when trying to access the S3 server log files through the API or the AWS console, the problem is caused by missing permissions (ACLs) on the log files.

To access those log files, the Open/Download permission should be granted for the user that owns them. Having a bucket policy with public read enabled is not enough to get access to the server log files.

More details on the issue are available in the comments below.

Comment: I am a little bit confused, because I already enabled the logging in the console but the documentation states that there are a fields that could be logged:  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=131329&tstart=0

Comment: I'm not sure you're looking in the right place. If access logs are enabled, there won't be any difference in the response that you receive from S3 after an API call. You should be looking in the access logs that are saved on S3, in the logging bucket that you specified when you configured your production bucket.

Comment: I am looking in the Bucket. (Its the same Bucket that is accessed). And there are a lot of files which only contain the quoted content.

Comment: Are those log files named in the following format: TargetPrefixYYYY-mm-DD-HH-MM-SS-UniqueString? (TargetPrefix is the key that you provided when you configured the bucket logging). If yes, do none of them contain anything else besides the quoted error?

Comment: One example file name is this: 2013-07-31-22-16-35-80805E1DA6CB1C4F, it doesn't seem that it contains the TargetPrefix. And I did not provide anythign I just enabled logging in the management console under bucket properties. And I am logging to the same bucket I am monitoring.

Comment: And what is the content of the file? Only something like <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code>....</Error>?

Comment: Exactly what i posted in my initial question. All the log files look exactly like that

Comment: Ok, I think I now understand what's happening. The log files that you're trying to access do not actually contain the error you mentioned, but when you are trying to access them through the AWS Console, you actually get an API error as a response because the permissions (ACLs) on those log files are set incorrectly (most likely there is no access granted to your user to actually view them). You should modify the permissions on the bucket log files and grant your user the Open/Download access. After that you should be able to see the actual content in those log files.

Comment: I set the bucket permissions in a way that its publicly acessible, because im serving public images from it. Does this rule: not apply to the logs? https://gist.github.com/KeKs0r/3a3c8a17d81dc9e7d910

Comment: I tested the bucket policy that you provided on a test bucket with logging enabled. I was able to confirm that the bucket policy does not cover log files. If permissions for my user are specifically removed from a log file, I get an AccessDenied error when trying to open that log file in the AWS console, even if the bucket policy is in place.

Comment: Can you please update youre answer that I can mark it as correct. And I created a new topic for the actual signature issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071842/amazon-s3-signature-not-working-with-sdk

Answer (score 0):

These look like responses that S3 sends back when the ACL/Grant permissions aren't set correctly. I'd check those first. If your bucket is behind a CloudFront distribution, make sure you invalidate the CloudFront cache as well.

Comment: I am not behind a Cloud front, I didn't setup any ACL stuff, just tried to make it publicly available (for serving images) and otherwise ill access it via API to store images.

Comment: Weird. That's a pretty old version of the SDK, but I'd be surprised if that were the problem. You're doing a HEAD request on the file using the SDK, but there's no query string authentication. Presumably because the file is already Public. Hmmm…