# Amazon S3 signature not working with SDK

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have random problems with my S3. I have several environments (several cloud / dev etc. machines). On almost all of them S3 is working perfectly fine. (I am using the PHP SDK with Gaufrette) The only exception is the productive environment which is not working. It has nothing to do with the bucket nor with my credentials. I provide the credentials via Environment variables and I have not changed them. During several deploys I have seen it working and not working in several occasions. I have no idea when it is working and when not. But as soon as I have deployed one codebase the fact whether it works or not seems to be fixed. Sometimes even an empty redeploy can solve the issue.

Here are the logs I am getting:
https://gist.github.com/KeKs0r/872af7eff4d723a589c5

I have read that sometimes the signature has problems with special characters or in some environment it has something to do with timezones? How could I check those settings and for what do I have to look? 
(I am working with AWS SDK 1.5.17.1)

This is one example signature:

> AmazonS3[x-aws-requestheaders][Authentication]: "AWS
>   MYKEY:pEU9UV/Yu1+7V71P55UuON8nGpQ="

Is the issue maybe caused by the / and the + signs? Why is the SDK not taking care of it?